# storing and printing values stored in an object array of a subclass of an abstract class

Tags: java, class, abstract-class, abstract

I've still learning java so bear with me.

Building off previous work. So I have a abstract Stock class with class ETF and class Dividend that both extends Stock class. ETF and Dividend override a calculatePrice from Stock. In another StockManager class, I can take some input as stock name, stock price, and either a value for ETF or dividend. Previously I stored these inputs into a object array

Stock[] stk = new Stock[STOCKLIMIT]

Now since Stock is an abstract class I can't do that anymore. How do I store these values? or print them?

Along with that, in StockManager you can add, remove, print, or find total cost of the stocks.

Deleted some things that are unneeded
Just need some help for adding, printing, and total cost

StockManager class

```
public class StockManager
{

   Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

   final int STOCKLIMIT = 6;
   int numberOfStocks = 0;

   Stock[] stk = new Stock[STOCKLIMIT]; //before stock was abstract

   String name;
   Double namePrice;
   int etfDividendVal;


   public void run()
   {
      String command = stdin.next();

      while (!command.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
      {
         if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
         {

            else
            {
               String commandTwo = stdin.next(); //either e for etf or d for dividend

               if (commandTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
               {
                  name = stdin.next();
                  namePrice = stdin.nextDouble();
                  etfDividendVal = stdin.nextInt();

                  //stk[numberOfStocks] = new Stock(name, namePrice); //object array when stock wasn't abstract

                  //store name, namePrice, and etfDividendVal somewhere now that stock is abstract

                  numberOfStocks++;
               }

               else if (commandTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
               {
                  name = stdin.next();
                  namePrice = stdin.nextDouble();
                  etfDividendVal = stdin.nextInt();

                  //stk[numberOfStocks] = new Stock(name, namePrice);

                  //where to store name, namePrice, and etfDividendVal somewhere now that stock is abstract

                  Stock stk = new Dividend();
                  numberOfStocks++;
               }
               }
            }
         }


         else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) //remove a stock
         {
            else
            {
               name = stdin.next();
               namePrice = stdin.nextDouble();

               for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStocks; i++)
               {
                  if (stk[i].getTicker().equals(name))
                  {
                     for(int z = i; z < numberOfStocks; z++)
                     {
                        if (z + 1 == numberOfStocks)
                           stk[z] = null;
                        else
                           stk[z] = stk[z+1];
                     }  
                     numberOfStocks--;
                  }
               }
            }
         }

         else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
         {
            else
            {
               // print stock name, price, and etf/divident value
               }
            }
         }

         else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
         {
            else
            {
               //print the total cost
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

Abstract Stock class

```
abstract public class Stock
{
   protected String commandTwo;
   protected String ticker;
   protected Double price;
   protected int etfDividendVal;

   public Stock()
// default constructor

   public Stock(String commandTwo, String ticker, Double price, 
                int etfDividendVal)
   {
      this.commandTwo = commandTwo;
      this.ticker = ticker;
      this.price = price;
      this.etfDividendVal = etfDividendVal;
   }


   public String getTicker()
   {
      return ticker;
   }


   public String setTicker(String name)
   {
      ticker = name;
      return ticker;
   }


   public Double getPrice()
   {
      return price;
   }


   public Double setPrice(Double namePrice)
   {
      price = namePrice;
      return price;
   }


   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return this.ticker + " " + this.price + "\t";

   }

   public abstract double calculatePrice();
}
```

ETF class

```
public class ETF extends Stock
{
   public float numberOfStocks;

   @Override
   public double calculatePrice()
   {
      return (price * numberOfStocks);
   }
}
```

Dividend class

```
public class Dividend extends Stock
{
   public float yieldPercentage;

   @Override
   public double calculatePrice()
   {
      return (price * yieldPercentage);
   }
}
```

It should look something like this

```
Pick an option:  A-Add R-Remove   P-Print    C-Total cost     Q-Quit
A
E
AMD
30.45
10
Pick an option:  A-Add R-Remove   P-Print    C-Total cost     Q-Quit
A
D
FXAIX
100
3
Pick an option:  A-Add R-Remove   P-Print    C-Total cost     Q-Quit
P
AMD 30.45 10.0
FXAIX 100.0 0.03
Pick an option:  A-Add R-Remove   P-Print    C-Total cost     Q-Quit
C
The total cost is: 307.4999999329448
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: “Now since Stock is an abstract class I can't do that anymore.”  Actually, you can.  Just like before.  Any variable or array may have an abstract type;  it’s the array elements that must be of a concrete class.  `Stock[] stk = new Stock[STOCKLIMIT];` is completely legal, and you may store instances of `ETF` and `Dividend` in that array, since an instance of ETF is an instance of Stock due to inheritance.  Same goes for Dividend.

Answer (score 0):

You can still create an array `Stock[]`, since `ETF` and `Dividend` both extend `Stock`, they can be added to the array. To use the methods declared in `ETF` and `Dividend` on the objects you retrieve from the array, you'll have to cast them, like so: `ETF etf = (ETF) stk[someIndexHere];`. Note that you don't know which objects are actually `ETF` and which are actually `Dividend`, and if you cast them to a type they actually aren't, you'll get an error. You can check if an object from `stk` is `ETF` or `Dividend` using the `instanceof` operator:

```
Stock stock = stk[0]; // Provided that there is a Stock at stk[0]

if (stock instanceof ETF) {
    ETF etf = (ETF) stock;
    // Now you can use etf as an ETF object
} else if (stock instanceof Dividend) {
    // The second if-statement is redundant since there are only
    // two possibilities, but in the future there might be more
    // classes extending Stock
    Dividend div = (Dividend) stock;
    // Now you can use div as a Dividend object
}
```

Although since neither `ETF` nor `Dividend` implements any new methods, casting is unnecessary. `instanceof` too, unless you want to tell your user which type of stock they're dealing with.

Comment: Since I can still create an array Stock[], would I just use the same way to store the input in it as I did before?

Comment: Yes, you can still use it to store input. But if you mean using the same input as in using the same stock creation then no, you're going to want to create an ETF or Dividend object instead of a Stock object, but you can still store them in the array.

Comment: In my sample input at the bottom, I would be storing AMD as the name, 30.45 as the price, and 10 as the ETF value

Comment: Well yes, you can use the same setters and getters seeing as ETF and Dividend inherit them and their behaviour from Stock

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've worked out the code without any problems.